# triple compound function $g=f\circ f \circ f$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I was wondering if anyone of you could help me to resolve this problem:

Calculate $g'(0)$, when  $g=f\circ f \circ f$   and $f(x)=x\cdot (x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+100)$.

Thanks, 
Felipe

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you for your answer. I will try to explain my questions in a better way the next time... Regarding the problem that I posted I haven figured out what to do. However, the chain rule of g=f(f(f(x))) is g'=f'f(f(x))\cdot f'(f(x))\cdot f'(x). and I think that f(x) can also be expressed as a product \stackrel[n=0]{100}{\Pi}(x+n)

Comment: Why are you thanking yourself?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

First notice that for any polynomial $h(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 +\dots a_nx^n$, $h'(0)=a_1$ i.e. the coefficient of the linear term.

Now notice that for any polynomial of the form $p(x) = a_1x+a_2x^2 +\dots a_nx^n$, we get $p^{(3)}(x) = a_1^3x+{\text{higher order terms}}$.

Now apply the previous observations for $p(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Hi Clark. Thank you for your answer, however, I can't see how to manipulate $f(x)$ to be able to use the chain rule.